# jQuery ready not fired after rails link_to is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

im using the javascript below to make an image "fade in" triggered by a scroll event. But the .hide im using to initially hide the image only works when the page loads initially, typing localhost:3000.

Once i'm in the site if i try to click a link to go back to the main page,

```
<%= link_to 'Main', root_path %>
```

the main page loads with out the .hide working

Why does the .hide work when the page initially loads but if i click a link to the same page the .hide does not work. the rest of the Javascript works no matter what, i can scroll and the image fades in and out depending on the scroll position, but i need it to start hidden, and that only works when the page loads initially help

```
function isElementVisible(elementToBeChecked) {
    var TopView = $(window).scrollTop();
    var BotView = TopView + $(window).height();
    var TopElement = $(elementToBeChecked).offset().top + 100;
    var BotElement = TopElement + $(elementToBeChecked).height();
    return ((BotElement <= BotView) && (TopElement >= TopView));
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#ghost_logo").hide();// hide it initially
});    

$(window).scroll(function(){
    isOnView = isElementVisible("#logoDiv");

    if (isOnView) {
        //fade out small image once main logo is in view
        $('#ghost_logo').fadeOut();
    } else {
        //fade in small image once main logo is out of view
        $('#ghost_logo').fadeIn();
    }        
});
```

Comment: where did you handle the click event?

Comment: I think u have gem 'turbolinks' am i right? check ur gemfile, if it true - i write  solution to u

Comment: Its a gem in Ruby-on-rails, it upgrade all links like .ajax, and $(document).ready didnt call

Comment: cool, and what makes you think he/she is using Turbolinks?

Comment: yes, it looks like i have turbolinks 2.5.3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are having a tipical problem with turbolinks, turbolinks make that DOM doesn't change when you navigate through a links, for this reason, the ready event from jQuery is never fired, you can solve this in three ways.

You can try something like:

```
document.addEventListener('page:load', function(){
    $("#ghost_logo").hide();
});
```

or if this doesn't work either, try navigate with out turbolinks change a parameter of link:

```
 <%= link_to 'Main', root_path ,{ :'data-no-turbolink' =>  "true" } %>
```

or if you want you can use this [jQuery-turbolinks gem](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks) is a gem provided for solving this kind of issues.

For more information refer to [turbolinks repository on github](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks)

Comment: how do you know he/she is using Turbolinks?

Comment: is very common issue on rails and turbolinks, when somebody says that his/her ready event is fired on refresh but not after navigate, usually is the well-know turbolink problem. And by default if you follow a tutorial or guides of ruby on rails, all use turbolink.

Comment: THANKS !!  i do have turbolink and that was the exact problem thank you, your first option did the trick. i will investigate further :)

Answer (score 1):

```
document.addEventListener('page:load', function(){
    $("#ghost_logo").hide();
});
```

Is not always working.
Better use:

```
document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', function(){
    $("#ghost_logo").hide();
});
```